# taking value from array using forEach.for print in a table row

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to take `tr` content in a json string using `forEach`. Successfully complete the first step but when the second `forEach` executing time it change the `tr` content that executes from first `forEach` condition. I am using this code:

```
 var collection = JSON.parse(data.GetPageInfoResult);

 collection.forEach(function (element,index) {
     // alert(collection[j].main.tittle)
     $(" tr[data-id='" + index  + "'] > td:nth-child(1)").text(element.main.tittle);
     $(" tr[data-id='" + index + "'] > td:nth-child(2)").text(element.main.discription);

     element.main.sub.forEach(function (sub, index) {
     $(" tr[data-id='" + index + "'] > td:nth-child(1)").text(sub.tittle);
     $(" tr[data-id='" + index + "'] > td:nth-child(2)").text(sub.discription);

     element.main.sub.task.forEach(function (task, index) {
     $(" tr[data-id='" + index + "'] > td:nth-child(1)").text(task.tittle);
     $(" tr[data-id='" + index + "'] > td:nth-child(2)").text(task.discription);
```

and my collection value is like this:

> [object] & data = Object {GetPageInfoResult:
>   "[{"main":{"sub":[{"task":[{"subtask":[],"tittle":"…ttle":"new","discription":"value","details":""}}]"

Comment: 1st and 2nd loop are editing same `$(" tr[data-id='" + index + "'] > td:nth-child(1)")` ... should not be same i guess. ( still not clear whats the requirements )

Comment: @MarcoS my question is  
suppose in my data have main ,sub ,task .i want main in data-id-1 then sub in 2 and task in 3 .but here the sub is overwrite in data-id 1